# Linux Eclipse 4.x popup window lost focus with unclutter

Tags: linux, eclipse, popup

With eclipse 4.x something differs with popup window focus handling. 
It is about 50% chance to lost focus when type Ctrl-e ("Quick switch editor"), Ctrl-o ("Quick outline"), etc.

The problem was with "unclutter" app which hides mouse cursor when you not move your mouse. 
Looks like it send pseudo EnterNotify event to the Eclipse when it hide mouse cursor.

So if start it like

```
unclutter -idle 2 -noevents
```

problem goes away.

Comment: Too bad I found this only now. It bugged me for years that eclipse sometimes behaved so strangely and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "unclutter" app which hides the mouse cursor when you not move your mouse. It looks like it sends a pseudo EnterNotify event to Eclipse when it hides the mouse cursor.

So if you start it like

```
unclutter -idle 2 -noevents
```

the problem goes away.

Other symptoms: A content assist popup opens and does not have the focus. Actually nothing seems to have the focus anymore. This consistently happens, if the popup opens over the place where the mouse cursor was before `unclutter` hid it. In my case the problem may have been even worse due to my use of focus-follows-mouse.

Another way to get rid of the problem: uninstall `unclutter`.